# Is it possible to install SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2017 Community?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I have Visual Studio 2017 Community installed on my computer, everything has been working fine. I decided that I wanted to mess around with Data Tools, especially SSIS, so I went online to install the SSDT. Before the install started, I got an error saying I needed to update VS 2017 which I did.

I later tried to install the SSDT with the updated version of VS2017 and received an generic Microsoft install error, simply saying

> Error installing

Is anyone aware if it is possible to install SSDT in Visual Studio 2017 Community? I've read online that there are only certain types of VS where you can install SSDT, enterprise being one of them. It did not say anything about community.

Comment: Yes you can install SSDT on community version

Comment: is there a special link for just community? @Hadi

Comment: No just select the Visual Studio installation from the drop down list as shown in the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#install-analysis-services-integration-services-and-reporting-services-tools

Comment: thanks @Hadi might be something wrong with my VS 2017 install

Comment: Try removing all Visual Studio installation and start a new installation from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes you can install SSDT on community version

Referring to the following [official comparison article](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/), Visual studio community has the same *Development Platform Support* as Enterprise and Professional editions.

To Install SSDT on Visual Studio community installation, just select the Visual Studio installation from the drop down list as shown in the following link:

- [Install Analysis Services, Integration Services, and Reporting Services tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#install-analysis-services-integration-services-and-reporting-services-tools)

It looks like there are a problem in the current installation. Try removing all Visual Studio installation and start a new installation from scratch.

Comment: I have done all of this and it is stall not an option for project when creating a new VS project. Must you have a specific version of SQL Server installed as well? I have both Express and Developer SQL Server installed. I don't think it will work with Express but will Developer